# Google Drive PHP api, insert file to drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

So basically the documentation in google developer is not updated to match the new version of their api.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client ();
// Get your credentials from the console
$client->setClientId ( 'CLIENT_ID' );
$client->setClientSecret ( 'CLIENT_SECRET' );
$client->setRedirectUri ( 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' );
$client->setScopes ( array (
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' 
) );

$service = new Google_Service ( $client );

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl ();

// Request authorization
print "Please visit:\n$authUrl\n\n";
print "Please enter the auth code:\n";
$authCode = trim ( fgets ( STDIN ) );

// Exchange authorization code for access token
$accessToken = $client->authenticate ( $authCode );
$client->setAccessToken ( $accessToken );

// Insert a file
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile ();
$file->setTitle ( 'My document' );
$file->setDescription ( 'A test document' );
$file->setMimeType ( 'text/plain' );

$data = file_get_contents ( 'document.txt' );

$createdFile = $service->files->insert ( $file, array (
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => 'text/plain' 
) );

echo $createdFile;
?>
```

And this is the error I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Google_Service::$files in D:\DATA\java\php workspace\Google Drive api test\quickstart.php on line 34
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in D:\DATA\java\php workspace\Google Drive api test\quickstart.php on line 34
```

This is the problematic line of code:

```
$createdFile = $service->files->insert
```

If you have any idea if I should be importing some other class or something please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with the same lack of new documentation, after I figured it all out, I made a simple example of how-to google oAuth, drive upload and folder creating in Google Drive SDK to help others. You can fork it on GitHub: https://github.com/numsu/google-drive-sdk-api-php-insert-file-parent-example

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have an object named $files that I can tell. Create a new instance of $files that conforms to what you are trying to do and then perform the insert. Hopes that help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's v3 you need to use create. Insert is not available in v3

```
$createdFile = $service->files->create( $file, array (
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    'uploadType' => 'media'
) );
```

Comment: Pretty sure that the contents of the "$file" are important.